# macOS keeps asking for root password in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, security, sudo, root

Today, my mac mini keeps asking for root password every time I enter Terminal or open new terminal window.
Android Studio and other apps that have terminal access do the same and keep asking root password.
I wonder if it's a security issue?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what a new window in terminal looks like? Can you also confirm what your "Shells open with" setting is in terminal preferences?

Comment: What shows that it's asking for the root password, as opposed to some script trying to use `sudo` and asking for YOUR password?

Comment: It sounds like you have something weird in one of your shell startup files (probably `~/.bash_profile` and/or `~/.bashrc` if you're using bash, or `~/.zprofile` and/or `~/.zshrc` if you're using zsh). I'd try temporarily renaming those, opening a new Terminal window, and see if that makes the password prompt go away.

Comment: Do you mean it's asking for your Mac password, e.g. so it can do 'sudo'? Generally you don't set up a Mac with a separate password for 'root' account, in fact having a password for the 'root' account is bad.

Comment: @GordonDavisson You're right, please post it as an answer.